# Gmaps4rails - Generic info window in model, but overwritten in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, partial, gmaps4rails

I have a model called store which have defined this:

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
 html_window = ''
 html_window = "<b>#{self.location_name}"
end
```

I want this window for all the maps that I render except for one that I want to create a infowindow from a template.

I have this code in my controller:

```
@list_of_stores = Store.all.to_gmaps4rails do |store,marker|
 marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => 'store_window', :locals => {:store => store}
end
```

I am able to render the window with the partial if I get rid of the `gmaps4rails_infowindow` in the model. Otherwise, the content of the windows is always the one that is set in the model.

How can I overwrite that? I want to have that method in the model, but in some cases I want to avoid using it, and just use what I have in a partial.

Comment: an issue has been filed in the github account. Will do, not available now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now available in v1.5.1, enjoy!